# Why don't my gold badges show up in my profile?

Tags: support, badges, user-profile, badge-tracking

In my Badges list, I have 1 gold badge (Famous Question).

[image]

In the "select your next badge" popup it said I have earned only one gold badge (Electorate), and the Famous Question badge doesn't show up.

[image]

The badge tracking bar it has only 1 gold badge:

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens?

Edit: My badge tracking bar just showed 2 Gold badges.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You can't track the Famous Question badge; basically, you cannot track badges which pertain to a single post. Some others might be too expensive (in terms of system performance) to track. See [this Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273929/295232) for more details.
2. The badge tracker says you've earned the Electorate badge, but that's not completely true; *right now* you qualify for it, but badges aren't awarded real-time; there's a script which awards them, but it runs at regular intervals. Therefore, the badge count in your profile isn't updated either. See the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298953/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange for more details.